# I got 400 bad request on blacklist when I logout

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, vuex, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to blacklist the user when the `logout` function called using  `django-rest-framework-simplejwt`. I can logout from the page but I keep getting 400 bad request in terminal. I believe that the token is not destroyed yet and also in my APIview I got `"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."`. Can you spot me the mistake?

[ Updated ]

error in terminal

```
Bad Request: /blacklist/
[21/Aug/2020 10:06:24] "POST /blacklist/ HTTP/1.1" 400 0
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=14),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}
```

views.py

```
class LogoutAndBlacklistRefreshToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            refresh_token = request.data["refresh_token"]
            token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
            token.blacklist()

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(
        'blacklist/', LogoutAndBlacklistRefreshToken.as_view(),
        name="blacklist"
    ),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path(
        'api-token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(),
        name='token-obtain'
    ),
    path(
        'api-token-refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(),
        name='token-refresh'
   ),
    path(
        'api-token-verify', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), 
        name='token-verify'
    ),
]
```

axios-base.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import store from "../store/index";
// API URL
const ApiUrl = "http://localhost:8000";

const axiosBase = axios.create({
  baseURL: ApiUrl,
  headers: { ContentType: "application/json" },
});

const getAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: ApiUrl,
});

getAPI.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function(err) {
  // if error response status is 401, it means the request was
  // invalid due to expired access token.
  if (err.config && err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
    // attempt to obtain new access token by running
    // 'refreshToken' action
    store
      .dispatch("refreshToken")
      .then((access) => {
        // if succesfull resend the request to get the data from server
        axios
          .request({
            baseURL: ApiUrl,
            method: "get",
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access}` },
            url: "/",
          })
          .then((response) => {
            // if successfully received the data store it in store.state.
            // APIData so that 'Downloads' component can grab the
            // data from it and display to the client.
            console.log("Success");
            store.state.APIData = response.data;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Got error while access token");
            return Promise.reject(err);
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  }
});

export { axiosBase, getAPI };
```

Vuex Store

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { axiosBase } from "../api/axios-base";
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    accessToken: localStorage.getItem("access_token") || null, // makes sure the user is logged in even after
    // refreshing the page
    refreshToken: localStorage.getItem("refresh_token") || null,
    APIData: "", // received data from the backend API is stored here.
  },
  getters: {
    loggedIn(state) {
      return state.accessToken != null;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    updateLocalStorage(state, { access, refresh }) {
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", access);
      localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", refresh);
      state.accessToken = access;
      state.refreshToken = refresh;
    },
    updateAccess(state, access) {
      state.accessToken = access;
    },
    destroyToken(state) {
      state.accessToken = null;
      state.refreshToken = null;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    // run the below action to get a new access token on expiration
    refreshToken(context) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axiosBase
          .post("/api-token-refresh/", {
            refresh: context.state.refreshToken,
          }) // send the stored refresh token to the backend API
          .then((response) => {
            // if API sends back new access and refresh token update the store
            console.log("New access successfully generated");
            context.commit("updateAccess", response.data.access);
            resolve(response.data.access);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("error in refreshToken Task");
            reject(err); // error generating new access and refresh token because refresh token has expired
          });
      });
    },
    logoutUser(context) {
      if (context.getters.loggedIn) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          axiosBase
            .post("/blacklist/")
            .then((response) => {
              localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
              localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
              context.commit("destroyToken");
              resolve(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
              localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
              context.commit("destroyToken");
              resolve(err);
            });
        });
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Logout.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Log out page</h3>
    <v-btn small color="success" class="mr-2 mb-5" @click="logout">
      log out
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Logout",
  methods: {
    logout() {
      this.$store.dispatch("logoutUser").then(() => {
        this.$router.push({ name: "Home" });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old, but I see there isn't an answer for it yet. So just in case someone stumbles onto this and was wondering what the problem is, it's likely because you need to add 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist' to the list of the installed apps in your Django project.